# Как можно переписать код чтобы автоматизировать открытие модальных окон?

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).on('click', '.lawcen', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $('.modalyak'),
  top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 0);
  $('.modal-lawcen').fadeIn();
});

$(document).on('click', '.exzaim', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $('.modalyak'),
  top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 0);
  $('.modal-exzaim').fadeIn();
});
```

Сейчас нужно для каждого модального окна прописывать js-код, можно ли как то заменить это на шаблон?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно присвоить всем одинаковые классы. Вместо `.lawcen`, `.exzaim` сделать `.modal-btn` например. Вместо `.modal-lawcen`, `.modal-exzaim` сделать `.modal`.

И соответственно одно модальное окно на странице оставить. Одну html разметку.

---

Если так принципиально использовать указанные классы, то:

```
let modalsData = ['lawcen', 'exzaim'];

for (let modal of modalsData) {
    $(document).on('click', `.${modal}`, function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      var id = $('.modalyak'),
      top = $(id).offset().top;
      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 0);
      $(`.modal-${modal}`).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

---

Ещё вариант через data атрибуты:

html

```
<input type="button" value="go" data-modal-type="lawcen" class="lawcen"/>
<input type="button" value="go2" data-modal-type="exzaim" class="exzaim"/>
```

js

```
$(document).on('click', `.modal-btn`, function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $('.modalyak'),
    top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 0);
    $(`.modal-${$(this).data().modalType}`).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: с одним модальным окном на странице к сожалению мне не подойдёт

Comment: @12marselo12 `data-` атрибуты кнопки используйте для указания какое окно открывать.

Comment: @12marselo12 добавил принципиальный вариант. Хотя я бы такое не стал делать, а переписал бы на одну модалку и универсальный класс

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там вероятно разный контент модалок.

Comment: @teran этот контент наверняка где-то можно заскладировать и подгружать в одно окно) кмк)

Comment: @12marselo12 добавил пару вариантов в ответ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, попробую второй вариант

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.lawcen, .exzaim ', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $('.modalyak'),
    top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: top }, 0);
  $('.modal-' + this.className).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Оставляйте более развернутые ответы.

Comment: а что тут добавить можно? Вроде все очевидно

Comment: Смотрите, как отвечают другие, смотрите какой ответ оставил товарищ Алексей Шиманский

Comment: Если Вы были бы внимательны, то как минимум не подумали бы, что это копия